# Replace new line javascript

Tags: javascript

Нужно строку

> \n в ам sfd vd \n\n\n \n \n \n \n
> \n\n\n\n  gffgn \n gf \ngf \n

превратить в

> в ам sfd vd \n\n gffgn \n gf \ngf

Вот сделал:

```
utils.parseText = function (text) {
    var map = {
        '&': '&amp;',
        '<': '&lt;',
        '>': '&gt;',
        '"': '&quot;',
        "'": '&#039;'
    };

    return text.replace(/([ ]{2,}|(\r[ ]+\n)|(\n[ ]+\n)|\t)/i, '').replace(/(?:\r?\n){3,}/g, '\n\n').replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) {
        return map[m];
    }).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
};
```

Но как-то неправильно. Исправьте.

Comment: []()  

    $.trim( text ).replace( /\n+/g, "\n" );

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, есть двойной перевод, а есть одинарный.

Comment: @exec, опишите подробнее принцип замен.

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, нужно чтобы в тексте было не больше двух пробелов.

То есть, один перевод строк остается, два три и больше преобразовываются в два. Между переводами строк могут быть пробелы - \n\n \n\n \n\n\n - это тоже нужно учитывать.